# Negattive loss and reconstruction loss in VAE

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am developing a VAE using this [dataset](https://github.com/Mereep/keel_csv/blob/master/standard_classification/onehot/shuttle.prepared.csv), I have used Keras tutorial and the developed the encoder and decoder myself, however, when I do the training the loss and reconstruction loss tend to negative increasing, I have seen some questions like this but I don't know what should I change in my case. Should I change the binaryCrossentropy?

data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('local path')
data, data_test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.20)
data = tf.expand_dims(data, axis=-1)
latent_dim = 10
leaky_relu = tf.nn.leaky_relu
data.shape #TensorShape([820007, 11, 1])
```

encoder:

```
encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(data.shape[1], 1), name='encoder_inputs')
x = layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation=leaky_relu)(encoder_inputs)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(32, 2, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(64, 2, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(64, 2, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(128, 2, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(128, activation=leaky_relu)(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(x)
z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')
encoder.summary()
```

decoder:

```
latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim, 1))
x = layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation=leaky_relu)(latent_inputs)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(128, 3, activation=leaky_relu, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(x)
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.20)(x)
x = layers.Dense(data.shape[1], activation='sigmoid')(x)
x = Reshape((data.shape[1], 1))(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Dense(data.shape[1], activation='sigmoid')(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, x, name='decoder')
decoder.summary()
```

VAE class:

```
class VAE(keras.Model):
def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
    super(VAE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.encoder = encoder
    self.decoder = decoder
    self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
    self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(
        name="reconstruction_loss"
    )
    self.kl_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")

@property
def metrics(self):
    return [
        self.total_loss_tracker,
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
        self.kl_loss_tracker,
    ]

def train_step(self, data):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
        reconstruction = self.decoder(z)
        reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.reduce_sum(
                keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=-1, keepdims=True
            )
        )
        kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
        kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
        total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
    grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
    self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
    self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
    self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)
    return {
        "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
        "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
        "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
    }
```

training:

```
earlystopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='kl_loss', mode='min', min_delta=0.005, patience=20, verbose=0, restore_best_weights=True)

vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.000005))
hist = vae.fit(data, epochs=20, batch_size=128, callbacks=[earlystopper])
```

Training values:
[image]

Comment: can you show us these negative values?

Comment: I have updated with the last 4 lines of the training values, it always keeps increasing in negative, do you know why? @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: "increasing in negative" - in other words, the loss is _decreasing_, which is exactly how it's supposed to behave, because optimizers are trying to decrease the loss.

Comment: Oh so it's my fault, I am new to VAEs and I haven't understood how losses are supposed to work, I might have to look at the theory again, thanks! @ForceBru